# How to vertically align text

Tags: tables, rotating

I am trying to vertically center text in a table but when I try to use `\vspace`, the entire row is shifted instead of just one cell. I have copied the LaTeX below that will demonstrate the effects if you use and don't use `\vspace`. I used the rotating command also which may be the reason this is so difficult.

Here is what using no vspace looks like, I want Lorem1 and Ipsum1 to be centered vertically.
[image: Normal Picture]

I tried to use `\vspace` to perform this task, but it doesn't accomplish what I want. I used a negative value in the example below.

[image: Picture using vspace]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}




\newcolumntype{E}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{7cm}}
\newcommand\RotText[1]{\fontsize{9}{9}\selectfont \rotatebox{90}{\parbox{2.6cm}{\centering#1}}}

\centering


\begin{tabular}{|c|E|c|}
\hline
&  & {Lorem Ipsum} \\ 
\hline
Lorem1 & Ipsum1 & \RotText{Lorem3 Ipsum3} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\lipsum

\begin{tabular}{|c|E|c|}
\hline
&  & {Lorem Ipsum} \\ 
\hline
\vspace{-10pt}{Lorem1} & Ipsum1 & \RotText{Lorem3 Ipsum3} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `[origin=c]` to the `\rotatebox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcolumntype{E}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{7cm}}
\newcommand\RotText[1]{%
  \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\parbox{2.6cm}{\fontsize{9}{9}\selectfont\centering#1}}}

\begin{document}

{
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|E|c|}
\hline
&  & {Lorem Ipsum} \\ 
\hline
Lorem1 & Ipsum1 & \RotText{Lorem3 Ipsum3} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
}

\end{document}
```

Notice also that I moved the font size change commands inside the argument of the `\parbox` to make sure its effect is kept local.

[image]

In a comment is has been requested to change slightly the shape of the table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcolumntype{E}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{7cm}}
\newcommand\RotText[1]{%
  \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\parbox{2.6cm}{\fontsize{9}{9}\selectfont\centering#1}}}

\begin{document}

{
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|E|c|}
\cline{3-3}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} &  & {Lorem Ipsum} \\ 
\hline
Lorem1 & Ipsum1 & \RotText{Lorem3 Ipsum3} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @sphere You're welcome! I updated my answer with a modification that could be of interest for you.

Comment: How can I get rid of the first two cells as well so that the table looks like this: _| shape

Comment: @sphere Please see my updated naswer. Is it something like that what you need?